# How to render $site_name without html tag?

Tags: theming

The $site_name variable get the name of the site wrapped in `<a>` tag but I want print only the value without html?

Is possible?

Thank you in advance.

> **EDIT**
>
> I'm using the strip_tags() function of php `<?php print strip_tags($site_name); ?>` but I don't know if is the best solution to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a [preprocess function](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) you can get the title like this:

```
variable_get("site_name");
```